# Yocto building image killed by oom

Tags: yocto

I'm trying to building Yocto image for IMX8MP Solid Run board. I have tried all the options: WSL, Docker, VirtualBox... But with all receive problems except VirtualBox. But VirtualBox is too slow, then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC.

Well, the process is much faster, but I receive a error related with "out of memory" when I do dmesg.

> oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/,task=cc1plus,pid=8425,uid=1000
> [262339.513607] Out of memory: Killed process 8425 (cc1plus) total-vm:1189540kB, anon-rss:1111296kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:2332kB oom_score_adj:0

I have tried with different Yocto versions (gatesgarth, hardknott...) but is the same error. I have tried to set up less threads at the same time, but is the same, The pc has i7 11700t and 16gbram all in one hp.

Where is the problem?